# Some questions about shared_ptr, scoped_ptr and shared_array

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, shared-ptr, scoped-ptr

I have some questions about smart pointers implemented in boost library.
Is the only diffrence between shared_ptr and scoped_ptr that scoped_ptr doesn't have copy constructor and shared_ptr has it? 
Should i use then scoped_ptr instead of shared_ptr always when object doesn't call copy constructor?
I also doesn't understand idea of shared/scoped array. Can't I just use std::vector instead of it?

Answer (score 10):

> Is the only diffrence between shared_ptr and scoped_ptr that
>   scoped_ptr doesn't have copy constructor and shared_ptr has it?

The difference is more fundamental than that; it has to do with how the smart pointers own the object it points to. What makes smart pointers different from dumb pointers is that the concept of ownership is a core component of their function. The ownership semantics is what differentiates the different kinds of smart pointers.

Because smart pointers "own" the thing they point to, they can do useful things like deleting objects when the smart pointers go away (this is made possible using only the rules of the language; no compiler magic is needed). This way, memory management can be made almost automatic in C++ (despite claims to the contrary, there's very little manual memory management required in modern C++).

- `shared_ptr` implements [reference-counting
  semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) for
  memory management. Multiple `shared_ptr`s can own a single object. A
  `shared_ptr` going away does not necessarily delete the object it
  points to because there may be another `shared_ptr` owning the
  object. The last `shared_ptr` that owns an object and goes away will
  delete the object it owns.
- `scoped_ptr` implements exclusive-ownership semantics. Only one
  `scoped_ptr` can own any one object. When a `scoped_ptr` goes away,
  it will always delete the object it owns (because there's only one
  owner). It's typically used as a lightweight RAII mechanism for
  objects allocated on the free store.

The array versions (`shared_array` and `scoped_array`) have essentially the same semantics, but are designed specifically for arrays e.g. they use `delete[]` instead of `delete`, implements the array subscript operator, etc.

`shared_ptr` and `shared_array` also allows you to specify a custom deleter, if the default `delete` behavior is not appropriate for the object. `scoped_ptr` and `scoped_array` do not have that ability, since they are quite lightweight compared to `shared_ptr` and `shared_array`.

In C++11, the newest and current version of C++, there's also a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which is just like `scoped_ptr` except that you can transfer the ownership of an object to another `unique_ptr`. In C++03, an older but more widely supported version of C++, there's `auto_ptr` which is equivalent to `unique_ptr` except it was easy to use it in an unsafe manner by accident (which is why it is deprecated in C++11).

> Should i use then scoped_ptr instead of shared_ptr always when object
>   doesn't call copy constructor?

Which one you choose doesn't depend on the presence of the copy-constructor, since `shared_ptr` and `scoped_ptr` does not require the object to be copy-constructible. You pick the one depending on the required ownership semantics. If the object will have multiple owners, you use `shared_ptr`. If the object will only have one owner and the object's existence lasts only within a scope, use `scoped_ptr` (hence the name `scoped_ptr`).

> I also doesn't understand idea of shared/scoped array. Can't I just
>   use std::vector instead of it?

`std::vector` does not implement reference-counting semantics like `shared_array` does. `std::vector` is more like `scoped_array`, but can be copied. When you copy a `std::vector`, you also copy all of the elements it contains.  That's not the case for `scoped_array`. `std::vector` also has functions that allow you to manipulate and examine its contents (e.g. `push_back`, `insert`, `erase`, etc.), but is much more heavyweight than `scoped_array`.

Comment: Just to add: The only difference of the array versions to the ptr versions, is that they call `delete []` instead of `delete`.

Comment: Furthermore, `shared_ptr` allows to pass a custom deleter that does additional/different things than destruction (eg. returning the pointed-to object to a pool), `scoped_ptr` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `scoped_ptr` does not allow for copies while `shared_ptr` does. But this "simple" difference makes a world of impact on both the implementation and the usage of the smart pointer.

`scoped_ptr` is faster and lighter than `shared_ptr` because no reference counting is involved. `shared_ptr` will count the number of assignments and not delete the object until all references have expired/gone out of scope.

Now your question regarding vectors implies that you're actually not familiar with the the concept of dynamic allocation and the difference between that and static allocation on the static. You really should look into reading a primer on C(++) and look into the reasons for dynamic allocation and when you need it.

A vector stores a *list* of objects. A `XXX_ptr` stores a pointer to a (single) dynamically-allocated object. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` is very different from `scoped_ptr`.  `scoped_ptr` (which is now standardized in C++11 as `std::unique_ptr`) is simply a RAII-style smart pointer which takes ownership of a resource and then deallocates the owned resource when the pointer goes out of scope.

A `shared_ptr` however, may share ownership of the resource with other instances of shared_ptr.  The resource stays alive as long as one or more `shared_ptr` instances own it.  This is an automatic memory-management technique, (a form of garbage-collection) known as *[reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)*.  It basically provides the same effect as more advanced garbage collection algorithms, except unlike other garbage collection techniques, it doesn't handle circular references.

As for using `std::vector` versus `boost::scoped_array`, yeah - `scoped_array` doesn't really offer much of an advantage.  However, `boost::shared_array` offers reference counting semantics, just like `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate memory, you can put the newly created pointer in a scoped pointer, so that IF the malloc/noew fails, the memory will be freed. This is how I usally uses it, or if it's an object that needs to be allocated on the heap, but that I want to treat it as a stack object in terms of that it will only be alive until the end of the scope.

The shared pointer is if you want to pass the pointer around and allow the object to have multiple owners. Then none of the owners needs to take responibility of the object and they can all just stop using it and be sure that it will be freed correclty. (you don't wanna free an object that you know is used by someone else)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're thinking about it the wrong way. The question isn't whether you *do* call the copy constructor -- it's whether you *need to* call the copy constructor. In other words, you should be deciding whether to use shared_ptr or scoped_ptr not based on reading your code but based on thinking about object ownership and what objects' lifetimes should be.

Say you have an object that you want to create on the heap, not on the stack, for whatever reason (maybe it's too big to be on the stack, maybe you might want to replace it with a different object at some point, maybe you want it to be initialized late) but its lifetime should never be longer than its containing scope. A common example of this is instance variables in a class: they should often be deleted when the object they are in is deleted. Then, you should use scoped_ptr.

But sometimes you don't know when an object will be safe to delete in advance. For instance, consider an object in a lookup table. You want to return it in response to lookups, but what happens when it's deleted -- could someone still be using the object who looked it up previously? In cases like this, you can use shared_ptr, which shares the objects ownership so that it only gets deleted when nobody has a copy of the pointer anymore.

So why does anyone ever use scoped_ptr instead of shared_ptr? First of all, knowing when the destructor gets called is one of the big advantages of non-memory-managed languages like C++. Maybe the destructor is expensive, or maybe it frees a resource; it's nice to know when these things happen. Also, with shared_ptr, there's the potential for memory leaks if you create a circular reference by accident.

In general, almost every pointer you have should be "owned" -- there should be a single place in your code that news and deletes it. scoped_ptr is great for this; when you want an owned object to be passed around to non-owners you can use a bare pointer. But if you absolutely need an object's ownership to be shared, use shared_ptr -- as long as you're careful to use it correctly!

As for scoped/shared arrays, you can certainly use std::vector, but arrays are cheaper and sometimes people want the performance benefit.

Comment: I doubt there's any performance benefit with `boost::scoped_array` over `std::vector`.

Comment: Not a big one certainly...but sometimes every cycle counts. I guess also sometimes you want to say "this is definitely just an array, I will never resize it or add anything to the end".